# Compare the value of DataGridViewCell to a dictionary and return the key

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am building a CSV Importer tool, now I have a dictionary that has a key value pair for the columns in the data gridview for comparison purposes.

```
 var events = row.Cells[2].Value; // class DataGridViewCell.Value
```

That has the value and I want to compare it to the dictionary that I have and return the key.

How can I do this without using Linq, if I have to use linq I need to be able to convert the key into a string like the following:

ID = "3";

Comment: It's not very clear what your input is, the output looks like just one string (as you posted), but what's the input data?

Comment: The input in that specified cell is : Cases

the reason for the dictionary is I have a unique key assigned to each of the value based on a CRM system.

Comment: What are the generic types of your `Dictionary`? in other words what are the types of `Key` and `Value`?

Comment: Dictionary<long, string> myEvents = new Dictionary<long, string>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `LINQ`, try this:

```
var x = yourDictionary.FirstOrDefault(entry=>object.Equals(entry.Value,events));
if(!x.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<long,string>))) { 
  var id = x.Key.ToString();
  //...
}
```

**NOTE**: if you do the same task many times, you should use another Dictionary whose `Keys` is the `Values` of your first Dictionary and whose `Values` is the `Keys` of your first Dictionary like this:

```
var inverseDictionary = yourDictionary.Select(key=>key.Value, value=>value.Key)
                                      .ToDictionary();
//Then use it like this:
long x;
if(inverseDictionary.TryGetValue((string)events,out x)){
  var id = x.Value.ToString();
  //...
}
```